# Angular cli build with AOT(--prod) is throwing error on run time on click of mat-autocomplete or any other material element

Tags: angular, autocomplete, msbuild, angular-material, command-line-interface

Angular cli build with AOT(--prod) is throwing error on run time on click of mat-autocomplete or any other material element, the error am getting is given below

```
ERROR TypeError: this._document.createElement is not a function
at t._createHostElement (main.dbeb1735f9287d0af752.js:1)
at t.create (main.dbeb1735f9287d0af752.js:1)
at t._attachOverlay (main.dbeb1735f9287d0af752.js:1)
at t._handleFocus (main.dbeb1735f9287d0af752.js:1)
at Object.handleEvent (0.6098c61070f0a4810ed2.js:1)
at Object.handleEvent (main.dbeb1735f9287d0af752.js:1)
at Object.handleEvent (main.dbeb1735f9287d0af752.js:1)
at cr (main.dbeb1735f9287d0af752.js:1)
at main.dbeb1735f9287d0af752.js:1
at HTMLInputElement. (main.dbeb1735f9287d0af752.js:1)
```

This appears only after building the angular 6 app with AOT(--PROD) and when clicking on mat-autocomplete element, this works fine without error when running the app with ng serve

Here is my package.json

```
{
"name": "mr",
"version": "2.1.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",

},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
"@angular/animations": "6.1.3",
"@angular/cdk": "6.4.6",
"@angular/common": "6.1.3",
"@angular/compiler": "6.1.3",
"@angular/core": "6.1.3",
"@angular/forms": "6.1.3",
"@angular/http": "6.1.3",
"@angular/material": "6.4.6",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.4.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.3",
"@angular/platform-server": "6.1.4",
"@angular/router": "6.1.3",
"@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
"ajv": "6.4.0",
"arrive": "2.4.1",
"bootstrap": "4.1.0",
"bootstrap-material-design": "4.1.1",
"bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
"chartist": "0.11.0",
"classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "2.5.5",
"googleapis": "28.1.0",
"hammerjs": "2.0.8",
"jquery": "3.2.1",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"ng-pick-datetime": "^5.2.6",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
"perfect-scrollbar": "1.1.0",
"popper.js": "1.14.3",
"rxjs": "6.2.2",
"rxjs-compat": "6.2.2",
"web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
"zone.js": "0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.7.1",
"@angular/cli": "^6.1.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "6.1.4",
"@angular/language-service": "6.1.4",
"@types/bootstrap": "3.3.32",
"@types/chartist": "0.9.34",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.8",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/jquery": "1.10.31",
"@types/node": "^6.0.73",
"codelyzer": "4.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
"karma": "2.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
"protractor": "^5.4.0",
"ts-node": "5.0.1",
"tslint": "5.9.1",
"typescript": "2.9.2"
}
}
```

Auto complete code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
<input type="text" placeholder="Choose SubCategory/Type" aria- 
label="Number" matInput formControlName="subCatogoryCtrl" 
(keyup)="changeMySubCategoryControl()"
[matAutocomplete]="auto2">
<mat-autocomplete #auto2="matAutocomplete" 
(optionSelected)="onSubCategorySelectionChanged($event)" 
[displayWith]="displayFn">
<mat-option *ngFor="let subCategory of subCategories" 
[value]="subCategory">
{{subCategory.name}}
</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Issue is not just with auto-complete all the material elements has same behaviour

Tried updating @angular-devkit/build-angular to 0.7.1 , its not working

Comment: Firstly, could you try updating all dependencies to the latest? It seems that you're using different versions of Angular packages (except Angular CDK and Angular Material). Lastly, could you insert the code for your autocomplete?

Comment: i tried updating all the packages, after update also its not working
appending auto complete code for you

Comment: <mat-form-field><input type="text" placeholder="" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="subCatogoryCtrl" (keyup)="changeMySubCategoryControl()"
                        [matAutocomplete]="auto2">
       <mat-autocomplete #auto2="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSubCategorySelectionChanged($event)" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let subCategory of su" [value]="subCategory">
                          {{subCategory.name}}
                        </mat-option>
                      </mat-autocomplete>
                    </mat-form-field>

Comment: not just auto complete, all the material elements has this prob

Comment: Could you consider _editing_ your question with the code that you've pasted?

Comment: @Edric, Updated the question